# React doesn't create the required elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code. It doesn't render the fullRecipe items at all but i see nothing wrong in here. I have trouble learning this framework and after asking nobody knows what's happening... Do you see what's wrong?

Thanks

```
class Index extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  render() {
    var list_results = this.props.recipes.map(function(recipe, index){
        console.log(index);  //Happens
        console.log(recipe); //Happens
        return (<fullRecipe recipe={recipe}></fullRecipe>);
    });
    return (<ul>{this.list_results}</ul>)
  }
}
function fullRecipe(props) {
    console.log(props || "no props"); // Doesnt happen
    return (<li><div class="delete-button">Delete</div>{props.name} - {props.ingredients}</li>);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fullRecipe` needs to  either be part of the `Index` class or made into another component.

You're also using `this.list_results`, which should be just `list_results`. `this` is the context of the whole class, whereas your `var` is local to `render()`.

The simplest method would be:

```
class Index extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  fullRecipe() {
    return (<li><div class="delete-button">Delete</div>{this.props.name} -   {this.props.ingredients}</li>);
  }

  render() {
    var list_results = this.props.recipes.map((recipe, index) => this.fullRecipe(recipe));
    return (<ul>{list_results}</ul>)
  }
}
```

EDIT

I'm not sure what I was thinking with the above. Really, it should be two components, and neither one needs to be stateful.

```
//Index.js
export default const Index = ({ recipes }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {
        recipes.map( ({ ingredients, name }, index) => {
          return <Recipe key={index} ingredients={ingredients} name={name} />
        })
      }
    </ul>
  );
}

//Recipe.js
export default const Recipe = ({ ingredients, name }) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <button className="delete-button">Delete</button>
      {name} - {ingredients}
    </li>
  );
}
```

Comment: By the way, semantically, that delete button shouldn't be a `div`. You may as well use an actual `button`

Comment: In the render function, `this.list_results` where is this defined?

Comment: Good catch, didn't see the `this` first. It should just be `list_results`

Comment: well.. the thing is i turned this upside down.. for once i copy pasted your code and.. still nothing .. :(
I ll make it it's own component but why wouldnt it work?

Comment: I think you also need to return a value from the `map` function. I've edited accordingly.

Comment: When using the arrow function the return is implicit.

Comment: Also a fun fact, the `this` context is not changed inside an arrow function either.

Comment: The real problem was the this.list_results.
I tried other forms of function , as a component. and it works great anyway as soon as we corrected the use of this.

Comment: Yes, without using the arrow syntax, `this.fullRecipe` inside the map function will throw an exception.

Comment: can you edit the answer to emphasize on the this being wrong? :)

Comment: Sure, but putting the function outside of the class was also wrong, even if it worked.

Comment: That function is essentially a class method. It belongs inside the scope of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect use of function/component

You can either create a Component called fullRecipe to display the information, or bring the function fullRecipe to Index component.

check this link https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html